# How to efficiently create a dict with key/value having the value as number of occurrences for a given key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

How to efficiently create a dict with key/value, where the value is the number of occurrences for a given key?

I'm currently doing like this:

```
dict_map = dict()

for car in data_frame["cars"]:
    if car in dict_map :
        dict_map.update({car : dict_counter.get(car)+1})
    else:
        dict_map.update({car : 1})
        
return dict_map
```

Is there any other way to do it in a more efficient way or using less code?

Comment: take a look at [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: `data_frame["cars"].value_counts().to_dict()` if you are already using `pandas`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually plenty efficient, just unidiomatic. Don't use `.update` here, and there's no need for the if-else.

```
dict_map = {}
for car in data_frame['cars']:
    dict_map[car] = dict_map.get(car, 0) + 1
```

But this is such a common use-case, the standard library includes `collections.Counter` which is just a dict subclass specialized for this very thing, and you can get this using

```
import collections
dict_map = collections.Counter(data_frame["cars"])
```

**However** since you are using pandas, you should use the built-in pandas API first.

```
>>> data_frame = pd.DataFrame(dict(cars=['a','b','c','a','a','c']))
>>> data_frame['cars'].value_counts()
a    3
c    2
b    1
Name: cars, dtype: int64
>>> data_frame['cars'].value_counts().to_dict()
{'a': 3, 'c': 2, 'b': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
dict_map = dict(Counter(data_frame["cars"])
```